# Wicket - Disable/enable Textfield using Checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, wicket

**UserPage.java**

```
public class UserPage extends WebPage {

public UserPage(final PageParameters parameters) {

    final CheckBox chk0 = new CheckBox("chk", Model.of(Boolean.FALSE));

    add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));

    final TextField<String> username = new TextField<String>("username", Model.of(""));
    username.setRequired(true);
    username.add(new UsernameValidator());


    final TextField<String> user = new TextField<String>("user", Model.of(""));
    user.setRequired(true);
    user.add(new UsernameValidator());

     user.add(AttributeModifier.replace("readonly", "readonly")); //Disabled Text Field

    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("userForm") {

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {

            final String usernameValue = username.getModelObject();

            PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
            pageParameters.add("username", usernameValue);
            setResponsePage(SuccessPage.class, pageParameters);

        }
    };
    add(form);
    form.add(username);
    form.add(chk0);
    form.add(user);
```

**UserPage.html**

```
 <div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
 <form wicket:id="userForm">
    <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="chk" />
    <p>
        <label>Username</label>: <input wicket:id="username" type="text"
            size="20" />

            <input wicket:id="user" type="text"
            size="20" />                
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
   </form>
```

I have 2 text fields.."username" and "user". **username** is Enabled Textfield and **user** is Disabled Textfield.

**But I need to Disable/Enable Textfield on click of Checkbox in JAVA.**
How to implement this? 
I am just a beginner.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou.

Comment: use `new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change")` on check box  update the text field with the status.

Comment: Thankyou... But Can you please explain programmatically with a demo as I am just a beginner.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Disable/Enable Checkbox on click of Checkbox'? Do you mean if they click it if becomes disabled and the user can no longer un-check it?

Comment: @roby OP meant disabling text field i believe

Comment: @Spandana ok tell me if check box `on` what do you want to disable and enable

Comment: Sorry..edited the question..Its enable/disable **Textfield** on click of checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using wicket 7.5

To make a click on your checkbox trigger an http request from the browser to wicket, update some state and re-render part of your page you should either add an AjaxBehavior to the CheckBox or use the convenience class AjaxCheckBox (which adds the AjaxBehavior for you).

I've trimmed down your example a little just to show how you could use the checkbox to enable/disable one of your text fields with a roundtrip to wicket.

### markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="chk" />
    <p>
      <label>Username</label>:<input wicket:id="username" type="text" size="20" />
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

### AjaxCheckBox

```
final Model<Boolean> checkboxModel = Model.of(false);
final TextField<String> username = new TextField<String>("username", Model.of("")){
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return !checkboxModel.getObject();
    }
};
//instruct wicket to write an id on the html element so it can replace it via javascript
username.setOutputMarkupId(true);
username.setRequired(true);
//AjaxCheckBox is 'A CheckBox which is updated via ajax when the user changes its value'
final CheckBox chk0 = new AjaxCheckBox("chk", checkboxModel) {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //re-render the username textfield
        target.add(username);
    }
};
add(username, chk0);
```

And here's an example using a behaviour instead of a convenience class.

### AjaxBehavior

```
public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    final Model<Boolean> checkboxModel = Model.of(false);
    final TextField<String> username = new TextField<String>("username", Model.of("")){
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return !checkboxModel.getObject();
        }
    };
    //instruct wicket to write an id on the html element so it can replace it via javascript
    username.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    username.setRequired(true);
    final CheckBox chk0 = new CheckBox("chk", checkboxModel);
    chk0.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    updateOnClick(chk0, username);
    add(username, chk0);
}

static void updateOnClick(Component a, final Component b){
    a.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("click"){

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(b);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Roby for explaining so well.. But im getting error at  -  **add(username,chk0)**  as (**The method add(TextField<String>, CheckBox) is undefined for the type Textbox**)  in **AjaxBehaviour**

Comment: strange, `add` should be a method on the UserPage class. Try doing `add(username)` and `add(chk0)` on separate lines.

Comment: Thankyou soo much@Roby....This is what I wanted.. add(username,chk0) worked now..:-D